# how to style border for radio button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm not able to create a style border for radio button.

```
  <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                Gender</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Male" type="radio" checked="checked"/>M<input id="Female" type="radio" />F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                What products are you interested in?</td>
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="Checkbox1">Widgets</label><br />
                <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" /><label for="Checkbox1">Hibbity Jibbities</label><br />
                <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="Checkbox1">SplashBangers</label><br />
                <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" /><label for="Checkbox1">Whatzits</label></td>
        </tr>
```

my try  in javascript is

```
function rock() {
        document.getElementById("Male").style.border = "3px solid red"
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        rock();
    }
</script>
```

css

```
input#Male {
border: 3px solid red;
}
```

jquery

```
$("form :checked").css("border", "3px solid red");
$("form :checkbox:checked").css("border", "3px solid red");
$("form input[id=Male]").css("border", "3px solid red");
$("form :radio:checked").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

all code is not working , please help me on this.

Comment: First, make sure you are giving same name to Male and Female radio buttons. Then only you can select either of those.

Comment: if it is the same its ok , if i query all the checked one and id  still its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/5ojpsqnv/).

```
input#Male {
outline: 3px solid red;
}
input#Female {
outline: 3px solid green;
}
```

Comment: ok thats great , i didnt use outline before , its working with css but how can do this jquery and javascript ?

Comment: I would advice you to use classes for css. https://jsfiddle.net/sachinnambiar/2o56rw4w/

Comment: your answer helped , finally found the problem its with the method outline any way thanks.